# Randomly Select a Node from N-ary Tree

Tags: java, algorithm, tree, nodes

My Node Class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Tree<T> {

    private Node<T> root;

    public Tree(Node<T> root) {
        this.root = root;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return (root == null) ? true : false;
    }

    public Node<T> getRoot() {
        return root;
    }

    public void setRoot(Node<T> root) {
        this.root = root;
    }

    public boolean exists(T key) {
        return find(root, key);
    }

    public int getNumberOfNodes() {
        return getNumberOfDescendants(root) + 1;
    }

    public int getNumberOfDescendants(Node<T> node) {
        int n = node.getChildren().size();
        for (Node<T> child : node.getChildren())
            n += getNumberOfDescendants(child);

        return n;

    }

    private boolean find(Node<T> node, T keyNode) {
        boolean res = false;
        if (node.getData().equals(keyNode))
            return true;

        else {
            for (Node<T> child : node.getChildren())
                if (find(child, keyNode))
                    res = true;
        }

        return res;
    }

    private Node<T> findNode(Node<T> node, T keyNode)
    {
        if(node == null)
            return null;
        if(node.getData().equals(keyNode))
            return node;
        else
        {
            Node<T> cnode = null;
            for (Node<T> child : node.getChildren())
                if ((cnode = findNode(child, keyNode)) != null)
                    return cnode;
        }
        return null;         
    } 

    public ArrayList<Node<T>> getPreOrderTraversal() {
        ArrayList<Node<T>> preOrder = new ArrayList<Node<T>>();
        buildPreOrder(root, preOrder);
        return preOrder;
    }

    public ArrayList<Node<T>> getPostOrderTraversal() {
        ArrayList<Node<T>> postOrder = new ArrayList<Node<T>>();
        buildPostOrder(root, postOrder);
        return postOrder;
    }

    private void buildPreOrder(Node<T> node, ArrayList<Node<T>> preOrder) {
        preOrder.add(node);
        for (Node<T> child : node.getChildren()) {
            buildPreOrder(child, preOrder);
        }
    }

    private void buildPostOrder(Node<T> node, ArrayList<Node<T>> postOrder) {
        for (Node<T> child : node.getChildren()) {
            buildPostOrder(child, postOrder);
        }
        postOrder.add(node);
    }

    public ArrayList<Node<T>> getLongestPathFromRootToAnyLeaf() {
        ArrayList<Node<T>> longestPath = null;
        int max = 0;
        for (ArrayList<Node<T>> path : getPathsFromRootToAnyLeaf()) {
            if (path.size() > max) {
                max = path.size();
                longestPath = path;
            }
        }
        return longestPath;
    }

    public int getMaxDepth()
    {
        return getLongestPathFromRootToAnyLeaf().size();
    }

    public ArrayList<ArrayList<Node<T>>> getPathsFromRootToAnyLeaf() {
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Node<T>>> paths = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Node<T>>>();
        ArrayList<Node<T>> currentPath = new ArrayList<Node<T>>();
        getPath(root, currentPath, paths);

        return paths;
    }

    private void getPath(Node<T> node, ArrayList<Node<T>> currentPath,
            ArrayList<ArrayList<Node<T>>> paths) {
        if (currentPath == null)
            return;

        currentPath.add(node);

        if (node.getChildren().size() == 0) {
            // This is a leaf
            paths.add(clone(currentPath));
        }
        for (Node<T> child : node.getChildren())
            getPath(child, currentPath, paths);

        int index = currentPath.indexOf(node);
        for (int i = index; i < currentPath.size(); i++)
            currentPath.remove(index);
    }

    private ArrayList<Node<T>> clone(ArrayList<Node<T>> list) {
        ArrayList<Node<T>> newList = new ArrayList<Node<T>>();
        for (Node<T> node : list)
            newList.add(new Node<T>(node));

        return newList;
    }
}
```

My Tree Class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Node<T> {
    private T data;
    private List<Node<T>> children;
    private Node<T> parent;

    public Node(T data) {
        this.data = data;
        this.children = new ArrayList<Node<T>>();
    }

    public Node(Node<T> node) {
        this.data = (T) node.getData();
        children = new ArrayList<Node<T>>();
    }

    public void addChild(Node<T> child) {
        child.setParent(this);
        children.add(child);
    }

    public void addChildAt(int index, Node<T> child) {
        child.setParent(this);
        this.children.add(index, child);
    }

    public void setChildren(List<Node<T>> children) {
        for (Node<T> child : children)
            child.setParent(this);

        this.children = children;
    }

    public void removeChildren() {
        this.children.clear();
    }

    public Node<T> removeChildAt(int index) {
        return children.remove(index);
    }


    public void removeThisIfItsAChild(Node<T> childToBeDeleted)
    {
        List <Node<T>> list = getChildren();
        list.remove(childToBeDeleted);
    }

    public T getData() {
        return this.data;
    }

    public void setData(T data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public Node<T> getParent() {
        return this.parent;
    }

    public void setParent(Node<T> parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public List<Node<T>> getChildren() {
        return this.children;
    }

    public Node<T> getChildAt(int index) {
        return children.get(index);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (null == obj)
            return false;

        if (obj instanceof Node) {
            if (((Node<?>) obj).getData().equals(this.data))
                return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.data.toString();
    }

}
```

How would I go about, after creating a tree, randomly select a node from said tree (root included). After selecting a random node from the tree, I need to be able to delete that node and replace it with a new subtree.

What would be the best way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: I would store the number of descendants on each node (which is easier if you always insert from the root like in a BST - but you can add one to all parents counts when you add a node). Then the root count is the number of nodes (almost) - so choose a random number in [0, numNodes). Then you can find it pretty easily by looking at the number of descendants on branches.

Comment: @sje397 How would you modify the node class?

Comment: Define random. Is "always root" random enough? Uniform distribution across all nodes? Something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This replaces a random node in the tree with a new node:

```
public static void replaceRandom(Tree<T> tree, Node<T> newNode) { 
  // Find a random node
  List<Node<T>> nodeList = tree.getPreOrderTraversal();
  int globalIndex = (int) (Math.random() * nodeList.size());
  Node<T> old = nodeList.get(globalIndex);

  if (old.isRoot()) {
    // If it is the root, we just replace the root.
    tree.setRoot(newNode);
  } else {
    // Otherwise, we need to find the local index to replace it.
    Node<T> parent = old.getParent();
    int localIndex = parent.getChildren().indexOf(old);
    parent.removeChildAt(localIndex);
    parent.addChildAt(localIndex, newNode);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finding a random node from the tree: 
Traverse the tree (using bfs or dfs traversal) and use a rand function while visiting each node. Give some constraints to the values that the rand function can return, bearing in mind the number of nodes of the tree so the possibility of choosing each node will be the same.